# Doctrine 2.1 - DateTime issue

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have `premiere_poland` column in database table which is `date` type.

```
/** @Column(type="date", nullable=TRUE) */
    protected $premiere_poland;
```

My issue is, that I want to store dates like `2012-01-01`, `2013-00-00`, `2013-01-00` etc. and I want that type of dates, but Doctrine every time returns that column data in DateTime instance and the true form is changed (for ex. `2013-01-00` = `31.12.2012`).

How can I make Doctrine to return this value as a string, not DateTime class instance.

My query:

```
    $q = "SELECT
            g,
            p.name AS platform_name, p.name_short AS platform_name_short, p.id AS platform_id,
            s.premiere_poland, s.premiere_world
          FROM Game g
            JOIN g.genres ge
            JOIN g.platform p
            LEFT JOIN g.specification s
          WHERE g.id = :id";
    $results = $db->createQuery($q)->setParameter('id', $_GET['id'])->getResult();
```

Comment: `2013-01-00` is not a valid date, therefore PHP's `DateTime` object and MySQL's `DATE` type should "cast" it into valid one. Anyway, why would you like to store such a strange thing?

Comment: Can you show a quick `var_dump($object->premier_poland)`? Everything looks correct in your setup according to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: @Crozin Because I need column which stores games date premieres and the premiere can be not fully known (for ex. March 2013 or only year). @Mike Yeah, but if I have `2013-01-00` in database var_dump will return me `string(10) "31.12.2012"`. And it's wrong ;p.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Thanks. Glad Crozin was able to provide a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @Crozin Because I need column which stores games date premieres and the premiere can be not fully known (for ex. March 2013 or only year).

I would suggest to create two columns, one for a date (of type `DateTime`/`DATE`) and another that would indicate what parts of date (day, month, year) should be taken into account when displaying a premiere date (of type `SET` or a bit mask).

Function that displays a premiere date could look like this:

```
// "parts" is a name of the last column - it should be renamed into something
// more adequate. Names of constants also aren't well adequate

function getFormattedPremiereDate() {
    if ($this->abc & Game::SHOW_YEAR_ONLY) {
        return $this->premierePoland->format('%y');
    }

    if ($this->abc & Game::SHOW_YEAR_AND_MONTH_ONLY) {
        return $this->premierePoland->format('%m %y');
    }

    if ($this->abc & Game::SHOW_DATE) {
        return $this->premierePoland->format('%d %m %y');
    }
}
```

Of course this function shouldn't be placed whitin an entity object - it'd be too complex (especially if we take i18n and i10l into account) and "unrelated" to the entity.

This techinque should let you show following dates:

- June 12, 2012 (`12-06-2012`, `Game::SHOW_DATE`),
- 2015 (`01-01-2015`, `Game::SHOW_YEAR`),
- March, 2012 (`01-03-2012`, `Game::SHOW_MONTH`),
- Summer, 2020 (`01-06-2012`, `Game::SHOW_SEASON`), Winter, 2010 (`01-12-2010`, `Game::SHOW_SEASON`)